# Umbraco Redirect users to home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am removing pages from a Umbraco website ( roughly 40 pages) and leaving three pages  -/Home - /Info -/About-us

I would like all other pages that no longer exist to take the user back to the home page. What would be the best way to do this making sure the visitor can still access the three pages left ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: Hello I am using Umbraco version 7.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using anything after v7.5, you should have access to the built in redirect management. In theory, if you add a page and delete it, it should get redirected to your homepage I think.

In the content section of the CMS you should see a redirects tab. Try adding a page and deleting it and see if a redirect appears in the list. If it does, you should just need to delete the old pages.